# "Unable to Start HTTP Connection" from Ion App

Tags: cordova, icenium

I have a good Internet connection.  Running the Ion app on IOS7.  When I press and hold three fingers for one second in an attempt to scan the QR code I'm seeing from Icenium Mist, it says "Unable to start HTTP connection."  Help!

Comment: I visited https://app.icenium.com via Safari (from my iPhone) and logged in via Facebook.  I then did a "Build" | "to Ion" option and when the QR code came up in Safari, I double-tapped it and was returned to the home screen somehow.  When I returned to Ion, I was then able to see my application.  I'm not sure if there is a more canonical or efficient way to get past that error message, though, but I'm happy that it's working now!

Answer (score 1):

Scanning the QR code from Mist and trying to livesync an already deployed app with the "three finger" are two separate things. For the latter, you already need an app that is deployed on your device via scanning QR code or by connecting your device to your PC (when using Graphite).
If the QR code has been generated it means the build is successful, the fact that it contains an URL confirms that. The "Unable to start HTTP connection." usually means two things:

1. You don't have internet connectivity enabled. Try to access to app.icenium.com where the .ipa file is stored.
2. Your QR code reader can't recognize the code as a hyperlink and that is why you get an erorr. Feel free to try with another reader, such as RedLaser or QRReader. You could also use the Download link to download the .ipa and install the app manually via iTunes.

Comment: Thanks for responding!  My QR code reader app (I was using one called ScanLife) appeared to derive the URL from the code, but all it would do was display it to me essentially in an "alert box" - it wasn't even navigable.  Not sure if it's because of the unusual icenium:// protocol.  I'll try other reader apps.  Thanks again!